# Jenkins job failed with Robotframework

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I am running a jenkins jobs that execute a robot test cases. jenkins on centos 7 remote machine. Error is as below once execute

```
python3 -m robot <test.robot>
```

> POLITY_123_Verify Subjects list blocks appears in Subject page
> | FAIL | WebDriverException: Message: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
> "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xez5U.png)

Comment: You need to configure Squid proxy to allow access to the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling for hours. will try and see. probably that access granting thing should be done by another team